# Swift - Rotating Image in 3D

Tags: swift, catransform3drotate

I am rotating an image in 3D depending on the orientation of the iPhone, with the following code: It works.

My questions are:

1. Is this an acceptable approach?
2. Is there are a single command I can use rather than building up three CATransform3DRotate in sequence.
3. Should I alter the .m34 value? 1.0 / -500 seems to be used a lot but I don't really understand the explanation of it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection#Perspective_projection

   ```
      let layer = panelView.layer
      var rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DIdentity
      rotationAndPerspectiveTransform.m34 = 1.0 / -500

      rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DRotate(rotationAndPerspectiveTransform, CGFloat(roll * .pi / 180), 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)    // roll
      rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DRotate(rotationAndPerspectiveTransform, CGFloat(pitch * .pi / 180), 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)   // pitch
      rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DRotate(rotationAndPerspectiveTransform, CGFloat(yaw * .pi / 180), 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)     // yaw

      UIImageView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: [], animations: {
           layer.transform = rotationAndPerspectiveTransform
      })
   ```

Comment: "Is this an acceptable approach?" That's too opinion based unless you clearly define what you mean by "acceptable".

Comment: For question 2, the "single operation" that you are going is converting euler angles to a rotation matrix. There is no single command to do that. You can try setting 9 of the 16 elements using the formulas [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles#Rotation_matrix) if you don't like `CATransform3DRotate`.

Comment: Acceptable translates into is this good programming. It struck me as very clanky to stack three similar commands on top of each other and surprised there isn't a single command that allows this to happen.

Comment: I love the CATransform3DRotate as doing Euler's transforms by hand is medieval (I know from first hand experience at University). The .m34 value still confuses me and most examples, that I have found, seem to go for this 1.0 / 500 value and would like to understand its rationale.